# "hello world" C program using hybrid of OpenMP and MPI

Tags: c, mpi, openmp

I'm trying to get a "hello world" program that uses both OpenMP and MPI working. I started with the example here

http://www.slac.stanford.edu/comp/unix/farm/mpi_and_openmp.html

but I can't reproduce the output. Here's the exact source I am using:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int numprocs, rank, namelen;
  char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
  int iam = 0, np = 1;

  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
  MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &namelen);

  //omp_set_num_threads(4);

#pragma omp parallel default(shared) private(iam, np)
  {
    np = omp_get_num_threads();
    iam = omp_get_thread_num();
    printf("Hello from thread %d out of %d from process %d out of %d on %s\n",
           iam, np, rank, numprocs, processor_name);
  }

  MPI_Finalize();
}
```

I am using a dual-processor Xeon workstation (2x6 cores) running Ubuntu 12.10. I have no trouble getting programs that use MPI or OpenMP (but not both) to work.

I compiled the source above using the command

```
mpicc -fopenmp hello.c -o hello
```

then ran using

```
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4
mpirun ./hello -np 2 -x OMP_NUM_THREADS
```

Here is the output I am getting:

```
Hello from thread 0 out of 4 from process 0 out of 1 on SteinbergT5600Linux
Hello from thread 2 out of 4 from process 0 out of 1 on SteinbergT5600Linux
Hello from thread 1 out of 4 from process 0 out of 1 on SteinbergT5600Linux
Hello from thread 3 out of 4 from process 0 out of 1 on SteinbergT5600Linux
```

I SHOULD, according to the example, be getting something like this:

```
Hello from thread 0 out of 4 from process 0 out of 2 on SteinbergT5600Linux
Hello from thread 2 out of 4 from process 0 out of 2 on SteinbergT5600Linux
Hello from thread 1 out of 4 from process 0 out of 2 on SteinbergT5600Linux
Hello from thread 3 out of 4 from process 0 out of 2 on SteinbergT5600Linux
Hello from thread 0 out of 4 from process 1 out of 2 on SteinbergT5600Linux
Hello from thread 2 out of 4 from process 1 out of 2 on SteinbergT5600Linux
Hello from thread 1 out of 4 from process 1 out of 2 on SteinbergT5600Linux
Hello from thread 3 out of 4 from process 1 out of 2 on SteinbergT5600Linux
```

Can anyone give me a hint as to what I'm doing wrong? As far as I can tell I am exactly reproducing the example in the link above.

Comment: You are required to use MPI_Init_thread with MPI_THREAD_FUNNELED for this usage of MPI and threads.

Answer (score 2):

You're specifying your program name as the first argument to `mpirun`, so the rest of the arguments are being ignored (Notably: `-np 2`). Thus, for `-np`, you got whatever is the system wide default value.

Change:

```
mpirun ./hello -np 2 -x OMP_NUM_THREADS
```

Into:

```
mpirun -np 2 -x OMP_NUM_THREADS ./hello
```

---

*Side note:* I tested this on my machine. The default for `-np` here is `3`. On your machine, it would appear that the default is `1`

Comment: Oh that's all it was... pretty dumb of me! I should note that this works without using Jeff's suggestion. The output is slightly different when I use both suggestions, though. Using my original source with the correct argument order, all four threads on the first process always display their output before any of the threads from the second process. Using MPI_Init_thread instead of MPI_Init, the printouts from difference processes' threads are interspersed. This suggests that the MPI processes may not be run in parallel when I just use MPI_Init. So it does appear to be required.

Comment: All bugs are "dumb" once they've been diagnosed and fixed ;-) MPI_Init_thread provides more generality/flexibility. The choice of MPI_THREAD_* is, in part, related to what topology you desire. Because you're also using openmp, that can have an impact. (e.g.) Without openmp, you might use MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE. But, with openmp, you might prefer MPI_THREAD_FUNNELED. YMMV Think of your needs first. Then contort the invocation to suit them. I usually create a script [with benchmarking] that can general all possible combos and then I select the final config based on analysis of the results.